# Logstash: Enrich event from log file with data from static csv file

Tags: logstash

Summary:
Use a filter in logstash that will read a value from event field, lookup this value in external file (e.g. csv) and retrieve value from external file that match. Use value from external file to add as an extra field in the event.

More info:
I have a log file with events. The events look like:

```
{"@timestamp":"2014-06-18T11:52:45.370636+02:00","location":{"MainId":3,"SubId":"5"},"EndRequest":{"Duration":{"Main":0,"Page":6720}}}
```

I have a static csv file like:

```
1,left
2,right
3,top
```

When an event is processed in logstash I want to be able to use a filter which will check value of MainId (in example event = 3) and find this value in the csv file. If found then the event must get a tag: "top".

It's kind of a similar way of the filter "GeoIP". The event has a field value, match value in a "database" and return values back which can be added to the event.

I was not able to find a current filter that could to above process. Do I need to make a custom filter myself? If so can some one give a hint how to approach this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've never seen a plugin written for it, so I went ahead and wrote a very basic one:

```
# encoding: utf-8
require "logstash/filters/base"
require "logstash/namespace"
require "csv"

# The cvslookup filter allows you to add fields to an event
# base on a csv file

class LogStash::Filters::CSVLookup < LogStash::Filters::Base
  config_name "csvlookup"
  milestone 1

  # Example:
  #
  #     filter {
  #       csvlookup {
  #     file => 'key_value.csv'
  #     key_col => 1
  #     value_col => 2
  #     default => 'some_value'
  #         map_field => { "from_field" => "to_field" }
  #       }
  #     }
  # 
  # the default is used if the key_col's value is not present in the CSV file

  config :file, :validate => :string, :required => true
  config :key_col, :validate => :number, :default => 1, :required => false
  config :value_col, :validate => :number, :default => 2, :required => false
  config :default, :validate => :string, :required => false
  config :map_field, :validate => :hash, :required => true

  public
  def register
    @lookup = Hash.new

    CSV.foreach(@file) do |row|
      @lookup[row[@key_col - 1]] = row[@value_col - 1]
    end
    #puts @lookup.inspect
  end # def register

  public
  def filter(event)
    return unless filter?(event)

    @map_field.each do |src_field,dest_field|
      looked_up_val = @lookup[event[src_field].to_s]
      if looked_up_val.nil?
          if !@default.nil?
            event[dest_field] = @default
          end
      else
        if event[dest_field].nil?
          event[dest_field] = looked_up_val
        elsif !event[dest_field].is_a?(Array)
          event[dest_field] = [ event[dest_field], looked_up_val ]
        else
          event[dest_field].push(looked_up_val)
        end
      end
    end 
  end # def filter
end # class LogStash::Filters::CSVLookup
```

There is further work that could be done on it -- for example if the src_field was an array, it could iterate over it, but it should work as is for your case.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your solution works perfect for me! I  did not expect an anwser so fast and complete. Of course if you start using this plugin, you come with new questions. I'm totally not familiar with Ruby. But looking for a way to give a default value when a lookup doesn't exist. BTW I did remove the "delimiter" as it gave an error, probably because it's not used?

Comment: I will update the code with a default option because that seems useful

Comment: added optional `default` config value for when the value isn't present in the csv file

Answer (score 5):

There is the Translate filter.

Instead of a CSV, you have a YAML file, and for single key-value pairs, that should be an easy sed yaml conversion

Latest doc at time of writing: http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/translate

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @UwePlonus yeah, the core/essentials of the answer was there, just not at the bottom :(