# Replace values with predefined mapping with ELK

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I have a file that I read with Logstash containing a certain parameter called `type`. The possible values for this parameter are 0,1,2,3,4,5 (it is actually represented as an Enum in my Java code).

Let's say type 0 means book, type 1 means newspaper, type 2 means magazine, etc.

Currently my Logstash filter writes this parameter directly as the number, but I would like to display panels on Kibana Dashboards that would show me the value (e.g. `book`) instead of the number (i.e. `0`).

Is there any possibility to add replacements or mappings to a list of predefined values at Kibana level? Or should I do this mapping manually at Logstash level with `if`conditions? What would be the best approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already got what I consider the best possible answer through Google Groups.

The answer can be found by following this link: https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/elasticsearch/88dajXfzSwk/80gVTXws8VcJ

It basically suggests me to use Logstash's translate filter: http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/translate
and I think is the best possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to do the replacement at the Kibana level, so your best bet is to use `if` statements if there are only a few options.

If you want to do something that is a bit easier to maintain, you might want to look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26062949/2785358 I wrote a plugin that can be used to read in a .csv file and then use it to enrich your events with data from the CSV file.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. It is probably correct, I won't be able to do it at Kibana level. However, I already got a better answer through a different channel. I'm posting the other answer as a SOF answer and of course up-voting yours, though not accepting. Thanks again!